# I keep getting an error, saying that D1D has not been defined?

Tags: java, variables, text, integer

I am making a planet exploration text game, where you choose from 5 different planets, each one harder than the one above it, but also more resourceful. I have the Int Variable: "D1D", as the danger value, that is randomised. I have a death screen thing, that activates if D1D = 1, but it keeps saying, that it cant find D1D?
(I am using JDoodle)

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PlanetExplorer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Planets:
        System.out.println("Explorable Planets: ");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Mars: ");
        System.out.println("Resorces: 50 ");
        System.out.println("Danger: 10%");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Jupiter: ");
        System.out.println("Resorces: 75 ");
        System.out.println("Danger: 50%");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Titan: ");
        System.out.println("Resorces: 50 ");
        System.out.println("Danger: 30%");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Uranus: ");
        System.out.println("Resorces: 100 ");
        System.out.println("Danger: 60%");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Neptune: ");
        System.out.println("Resorces: 150 ");
        System.out.println("Danger: 75%");
        //Detecting the planet
        Scanner Planet1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String P1 = Planet1.next();
        // D_R = Day (1-5) Resources
        // D_D = Day (1-5) Danger
        //If Mars:
        if ((P1.equals("Mars"))) {
            int min = 1;
            int max = 90;
            int range = max - min + 1;
            int  D1R = 50;
            int D1D = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
            
            // If Jupier
        }
        if ((P1.equals("Jupiter"))) {
            int min = 1;
            int max = 50;
            int range = max - min + 1;
            int  D1R = 100;
            int D1D = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
            
            //If Titan
        }
        if ((P1.equals("Titan"))) {
            int min = 1;
            int max = 70;
            int range = max - min + 1;
            int  D1R = 50;
            int D1D = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
            
            //If Uranus
        }
        if ((P1.equals("Uranus"))) {
            int min = 1;
            int max = 40;
            int range = max - min + 1;
            int  D1R = 60;
            int D1D = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
            
            //If Neptune
        }
        if ((P1.equals("Neptune"))) {
            int min = 1;
            int max = 25;
            int range = max - min + 1;
            int  D1R = 150;
            int D1D = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
        }
         //Here \|/
        if (D1D = 1) {
            int Mmin = 1;
            int Mmax = 3;
            int Mrange = Mmax - Mmin + 1;
            int Message = (int)(Math.random() * Mrange) + Mmin;
            if (Message == 1) {
            System.out.println("You Died!");
            System.out.println("Better Luck Next Time!");
            }
            else {
                if (Message == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Failure!");
                }
                else {
                    if (Message == 3) {
                        System.out.println("You Died!");
                        System.out.println("Replay?");
                    }
                }
            }
        }





    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, `if (D1D = 1)` is an incorrect check, it should be `if (D1D == 1)`. Second of all, you define your integers (for example `int D1D`) in all these different if clauses. This means, the scope of the defined variables is limited to the scope of the if-clause. Therefore, once out of the if-clause, you can not access the variables, because they are out of scope. The solution would be to define your variables at the beginning, outside of the `if`s and only initialize them later on.

Comment: Sidenote: Variable names should start lowercase and be discriptive.

Comment: But then, how am I going to edit the integers, once they are defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are declaring your variables locally (new within each if-block).
After the if-block the variable is gone again.

you should declare the variables before:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int min, max, range, Message, D1R, D1D;
```

and the only assign values to them in the if-blocks:

```
    if ((P1.equals("Neptune"))) {
        min = 1;
        max = 25;
        range = max - min + 1;
        D1R = 150;
        D1D = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
```

you will have some more problems compiling this since the variable names are not consistent, but I hope this will help you.

Comment: It is working, but now it is saying "variable D1D might not have been initialised"

Comment: @Yeetus yes, because there might be occurences (for example if input doesn't equal any of the provided checks) where you never initialize it. In this case, before using the variable you might have to check if it has been initialized or you initialize it beforehand with some default value you might find suitable.

Comment: I fixed it :). All I had to do, was add: D1D = 0;, at the beginning, after it was defined.